# Django: Adding many-to-many relations within post_save

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django 2.0 and I'm trying to create a simple Event app with auto opt-in functionality. I.e. `Member`s with certain statuses are automatically signed up for the `Event` when it is created.

To do that, I used Django's `post_save` signal to create a queryset of the affected `Member`s and add them to the `Event`'s many-to-many field, `participants`.

```
@receiver(signal=post_save, sender='events.Event')
def auto_opt_in(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # Only applies to new Events that are opt-out
    if created and instance.is_opt_out:
            from database.models import Member

            # Build queryset of affected members
            members = Member.objects.none()
            for status in instance.opt_out_member_statuses:
                members = members.union(Member.objects.filter(member_status=status))

            # Add members to Event
            instance.participants.add(*members)
            instance.save()
```

My problem now is that the `Members` are not actually added to the `Event`. If I put `print(instance.participants.all())` after the last line, it outputs the correct result. However, the changes do not appear to be committed to the database. What am I missing? Are you not allowed to make changes to the instance? If so, what's the point?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need that loop; you just need `Member.objects.filter(member_status__in=instance.opt_out_member_statuses)`. Also you don't need to save after adding to a many-to-many.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Thanks! That's a lot neater (and probably quicker). However, the original problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

you need  to do this:

```
from django.db import transaction

transaction.on_commit(lambda: instance.cou_group.add(instance.participants.add(*members))
```

why? i'm not sure

Comment: If you're not sure you should try looking for some more info on the subject and editing your post so it is more helpful to people that come here.